Can I get the previous binary archive of apache httpd server for Windows?
Can I get the previous binary archive of apache httpd server for Windows?
Are archived versions available on Apache httpd or can anyone point me to where I can find an older Win version?
please, thank you
Are the downloads for previous versions for Windows still available somewhere?

This may not be the best fit for this site -- see #3 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

@dat If they're looking for official documentation/archives, that could be on topic.
